# Gamma GLMM Dispersion, Random Effects, and CoV (lme4)

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, glmm, gamma-distribution, coefficient-of-variation

So I know that in glm(), with the Gamma family, one can get the dispersion parameter through the MASS package with gamma.dispersion() or can even look at the summary output as a quick estimate.

How does one get the estimate of dispersion in a Gamma GLMM?

Also, what is the interpretation of the variance/std dev in Gamma GLMM? Are these already in the CoV units or are they in the units of the original data?

What I mean is, when I read off the std dev in a Gamma GLMM, do I interpret that as the std dev with the same units as the response variable as in a regular LMM, or is it already a proportion?

Comment: Hey OP did you ever find an answer for this? I have the same question...

Comment: Yea I did eventually. Basically, even for GLMMs, random effects are assumed as Multivariate Normal on the link scale. (So for random effects, a link works like a transformation). So then even if its a random intercept but you use identity link, its SD has units of the response variable. If you use log link, it has units of log(Y) which would then approximately be a CoV on the original scale. However, the residual SD shown in the output of a Gamma GLMM in glmer() is a CoV no matter what link. This is the confusing thing.